# How can I byte stream a video file placing it outside the WWW folder in apache server

Tags: php, apache, video

In my server (Apache) I have a few video files (.mp4) that I play on the site directly in browser. But the video files are placed in /var/www/videos folder in ubuntu. Now if I place the videos folder in /var folder ( /var/videos) the video streaming doesn't take place. can anybody please tell me how to achive this?? I tried byte streaming also but video files is either getting corrupted or byte streaming doesn't take place

Here is my code what i tried with :

```
   <?php

function set_range($range, $filesize, &$first, &$last){
  /*
  Sets the first and last bytes of a range, given a range expressed as a string 
  and the size of the file.

  If the end of the range is not specified, or the end of the range is greater 
  than the length of the file, $last is set as the end of the file.

  If the begining of the range is not specified, the meaning of the value after 
  the dash is "get the last n bytes of the file".

  If $first is greater than $last, the range is not satisfiable, and we should 
  return a response with a status of 416 (Requested range not satisfiable).

  Examples:
  $range='0-499', $filesize=1000 => $first=0, $last=499 .
  $range='500-', $filesize=1000 => $first=500, $last=999 .
  $range='500-1200', $filesize=1000 => $first=500, $last=999 .
  $range='-200', $filesize=1000 => $first=800, $last=999 .

  */

  $dash=strpos($range,'-');
  $first=trim(substr($range,0,$dash));
  $last=trim(substr($range,$dash+1));
  if ($first=='') {

    $suffix=$last;
    $last=$filesize-1;
    $first=$filesize-$suffix;
    if($first<0) $first=0;
  } else {
    if ($last=='' || $last>$filesize-1) $last=$filesize-1;
  }
  if($first>$last){

    header("Status: 416 Requested range not satisfiable");
    header("Content-Range: */$filesize");
    exit;
  }
}

function buffered_read($file, $bytes, $buffer_size=1024){
  /*
  Outputs up to $bytes from the file $file to standard output, $buffer_size bytes at a time.
  */
  $bytes_left=$bytes;
  while($bytes_left>0 && !feof($file)){
    if($bytes_left>$buffer_size)
      $bytes_to_read=$buffer_size;
    else
      $bytes_to_read=$bytes_left;
    $bytes_left-=$bytes_to_read;
    $contents=fread($file, $bytes_to_read);
    echo $contents;
    flush();
  }
}

function byteserve($filename){
  /*
  Byteserves the file $filename.  

  When there is a request for a single range, the content is transmitted 
  with a Content-Range header, and a Content-Length header showing the number 
  of bytes actually transferred.

  When there is a request for multiple ranges, these are transmitted as a 
  multipart message. The multipart media type used for this purpose is 
  "multipart/byteranges".
  */

  $filesize=filesize($filename);
  $file=fopen($filename,"rb");

  $ranges=NULL;
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) && $range=stristr(trim($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']),'bytes=')){
    $range=substr($range,6);
    $boundary='g45d64df96bmdf4sdgh45hf5';//set a random boundary
    $ranges=explode(',',$range);
  }

  if($ranges && count($ranges)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial content");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    if(count($ranges)>1){


      //compute content length
      $content_length=0;
      foreach ($ranges as $range){
        set_range($range, $filesize, $first, $last);
        $content_length+=strlen("\r\n--$boundary\r\n");
        $content_length+=strlen("Content-type: video/mp4\r\n");
        $content_length+=strlen("Content-range: bytes $first-$last/$filesize\r\n\r\n");
        $content_length+=$last-$first+1;          
      }
      $content_length+=strlen("\r\n--$boundary--\r\n");

      //output headers
      header("Content-Length: $content_length");

      header("Content-Type: multipart/x-byteranges; boundary=$boundary");


      foreach ($ranges as $range){
        set_range($range, $filesize, $first, $last);
        echo "\r\n--$boundary\r\n";
        echo "Content-type: video/mp4\r\n";
        echo "Content-range: bytes $first-$last/$filesize\r\n\r\n";
        fseek($file,$first);
        buffered_read ($file, $last-$first+1);          
      }
      echo "\r\n--$boundary--\r\n";
    } else {

      $range=$ranges[0];
      set_range($range, $filesize, $first, $last);  
      header("Content-Length: ".($last-$first+1) );
      header("Content-Range: bytes $first-$last/$filesize");
      header("Content-Type: video/mp4");  
      fseek($file,$first);
      buffered_read($file, $last-$first+1);
    }
  } else{

    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Content-Length: $filesize");
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    readfile($filename);
  }
  fclose($file);
}

function serve($filename, $download=0){
  //Just serves the file without byteserving
  //if $download=true, then the save file dialog appears
  $filesize=filesize($filename);
  header("Content-Length: $filesize");
  header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
  $filename_parts=pathinfo($filename);
  if($download) header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename_parts['basename']);
  readfile($filename);
}


set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);


ini_set('session.cache_limiter','none');



$filename='/var/videos/guruthva.mp4'; //this is the  file that will be byteserved
byteserve($filename); 

?>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: So if you move it, it suddenly doesn't work? Should be something with either paths or unix rights (and ownership). Have you checked both? Do you see anything in apache's error log? Any other error messages?

Comment: No the issue is not with the unix rights and ownership. If the videos folder is present inside WWW (web-server) folder then apache does the byte streaming. since the videos folder is outside webserver byte streaming is to be done manually... and i tried with above code. but no result

Comment: Right, in that case you really should narrow down your question and provide some more debugging information. Because as it is now it is a ["why isn't this code working"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question...